# multiplying lists function, did not understand the output.python

Tags: python

I have encountered this function:

```
    def square_it(var):
    return [var *2] *2

zoo = (square_it([1]))
zoo[1][0] +=1
print(zoo)
```

I dont understand why the output is: [[2, 1],[2,1]] and not [[1, 1], [2, 1]]
can someone please explain this?
Thanks.

Comment: `[var *2] *2` is returning a list of the same element twice...

Comment: so do you mean both elements have the same address when you multiply a list?

Comment: Give the dup link a read, it's the same issue you have, basically if you look at the memory location of both sub lists, you will see that they are the same object, using the same memory

Comment: `square_it` returns a list with 2 elements that is the same object.
lets assume that `var *2` is object `A` (equals to `[1, 1]`)
then `[var *2] *2` is `[A, A]`
later you are accessing the function result as `zoo[1]`. that would be `A`.

try to check `zoo[0] is zoo[1]`. That is the same object

Comment: @Efrat.shp it is generally not very helpful to think about addresses in Python. Suffice it to say, *they are the same object*. I.E. `zoo[0] is zoo[1]`